# Perl - parse string to integer from arguments and compare it

Tags: string, perl, compare

There are two arguments: `$a` and `$b`, and both are strings. They are will be compared, if a is greater/less/equal to b.

Other people can achieve 42 char, I don't know how to achieve it.

```
AUTOLOAD { 
    $_[0] + 0 > $_[1] + 0 ? "greater" :
    $_[1] == $_[0] ? "equal" : "less"
}
```

Comment: Instead of assigning variables `$a` and `$b` you could extract directly from the `@_` array for example

Comment: how to extract it? @HåkonHægland

Comment: Have a look at https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Comment: AUTOLOAD { 
    $_[0]>$_[1]?"greater":$_[0]<$_[1]?"less":"equal"
}
need the shorter

Comment: What is *"Other people can achieve 42 char"*? Is this a code golf competition?

Comment: I think you've probably read something that you didn't understand. We can't disabuse you of your misconceptions unless you give a lot more detail about your circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask, but you give almost no information on your program so it is very difficult to suggest anything

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for ( [ 1, 2 ], [2, 2], [3, 2] ) {
    my ($aa, $bb) = @$_;
    printf "%d is %s %d\n", $aa, compare($aa, $bb), $bb;
}

sub compare {
    my ($aa, $bb) = @_;

    ('less than', 'equal to', 'greater than')[($aa <=> $bb) + 1];
}
```

#### output

```
1 is less than 2
2 is equal to 2
3 is greater than 2
```

Comment: I was considering `('equal to', 'greater than', 'less than')[ $a <=> $b ]` which avoids the need to add one. But might be a little obscure :-)

Comment: Yes, I was similarly wary of that option! I also considered `no warnings 'deprecated';
 local $[ = -1;` but I doubt if `$[` has much longer to live with the current state of affairs.

Comment: no, this too long, i was trying to shorten the code. My code is simple. There are two argument will be passed to autoload, $a and $b as a string. and we will compare it and return "greater" or "less" or "equals"

Comment: AUTOLOAD { 
    ("equal","greater","less")[$_[0] <=> $_[1]];
}

here how i do it.

Comment: The length of a piece of code isn't a good measure of its quality. In fact, **Dave Cross** says in his comment that it may be too obscure. What are you doing that requires your code to be so short? Why are you using `AUTOLOAD`?